# jQuery UI Sortable - Disable sideways movement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

With the jQuery UI's sortable function, a user can move the div in any direction. I only want the user to be able to drag it up and down. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specific to sortable:

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis

`$( ".selector" ).sortable({ axis: "y" });`

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
$('#items_wrapper').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',
     ...
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the axis method. See the api [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis).